# Salseforce Apex classes support Apache axis Stub authentication

Tags: web-services, salesforce, apex-code, axis

We have converted a WSDL file of a Web serivice into the salesforce apex classes. The Web Service is receiving the authentication credentials in Apache axis Stub authentication username and password format.

**Below is the sample Apache axis Stub authentication username and password code.**

```
Service service = new  XYZServiceLocator();
URL endpointURL = new URL("https://urllink");
XYZServiceSoapBindingStub stub = new XYZServiceSoapBindingStub(endpointURL, service);
stub.setUsername("username");// void org.apache.axis.client.Stub.setUsername(String username)
stub.setPassword("password");// void org.apache.axis.client.Stub.setPassword(String Password)
QueryResponse qresp = stub.webServiceCall(qr);
```

My question is. Can we get the Apache axis Stub authentication username and password functionality in the salesforce Apex classes.

As the Apex Stub support the HTTP Headers authentication does it also support the  Apache axis Stub authentication?

**Below is the Salesforce Apex stub HTTP Headers authentication code**

```
String myData = 'username:password';
Blob hash = Crypto.generateDigest('SHA1',Blob.valueOf(myData));
encodedusernameandpassword = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hash);
XYZBillingStub.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Authorization','Basic ' + encodedusernameandpassword );// SALESFORCE STUB
XYZBilling.query(queryReq )// Web Service call
```

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After converting the apex code to the below code I was successfully able to resolve the issue.

```
String myData = 'username:password';
encodedusernameandpassword = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(myData));
XYZBillingStub.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Authorization','Basic ' + encodedusernameandpassword );// SALESFORCE STUB
XYZBilling.query(queryReq )// Web Service call
```

This was a simple hit and trial solution I got, And I think Salseforce apex functionality only support input HTTP Headers authentication process. If one has some other way to do the authentication please mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already figured out a solution.

For reference, have a look at the [Sending HTTP Headers on a Web Service Callout](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm#http_header_support) section of the online docs for doing basic authentication headers.